# railsinstaller 2.2.1 fails on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

i downloaded the rails installer and tried to install, but i get the error in the screenshot. I have re-downloaded the file several times and installed times over, but without success.

[image: railsinstaller error]

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with version 2.2.2? Additionally, any issues with the installer should be reported in [Github Issues](http://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/issues).

Evan